# How to get on_change value of select widget in bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to display selected value of select() bokeh widget in my browser.

This is my code, where I have data frame and values and that is how my widget gets populated !!!

```
multi_select = Select (title = "Select Quarters" , value = str1, options = df)
```

This is how it is calling using this function!!

```
def function_to_call(attrname, old, new):
  print(multi_select.value)
```

This is my HTML template which will call select value .

```
text=("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      {{ bokeh_css }}
      {{ bokeh_js }}
   </head>
   <body>
      <style type="text/css">
         {% include 'styles.css' %}
      </style>
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
      {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
      <div>
         <h1 style="color:#8CC43F">{selectval}</h1>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
""")
```

Here {selectval} value is replacing my multi_select value from dropdown!!

```
m =multi_select.on_change('value',function_to_call)
text = text.format(selectval=m)
div = Div(text=text,width=200, height=100)
```

This is how i am calling the widget

```
curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(multi_select,div))
```

After doing this, it is still not displaying the value of my selected option from the select list. For example, if I am selecting Quarter-4 then it should display as text Quarter-4 in my div or textbox on "my browser" screen.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The function you showed will print something in the terminal

Comment: Yes but i want in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you can change the text of the div widget directly

```
def function_to_call(attrname, old, new):
  div.text = new
```

Here `attrname` is 'value'

`old` is the value of the Select widget before it was changed

`new` is the new value of the Select widget

Comment: `div.text = multi_select.value` will also work. FWIW your question seems mis-titlled. You know how to get the select value, what you needed to know was how to use that value to set the div text.